# how to count the number a button is pressed and print the total number pressed on screen

Tags: python, button, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
app = Tk()
app.title("quiz")
app.geometry('300x100+200+100')
b1 = Button(app, text = "correct!", width = 10,
            command = play_correct)
b1.pack(side ='left', padx = 10, pady = 10)
b2 = Button(app, text = "wrong!", width = 10,
            command = play_wrong)
b2.pack(side ='right', padx = 10, pady = 10)
```

what do I do so that when I type number_asked on shell,
I get the total number of the correct AND the wrong button pressed;
when I type number_correct, I get the total number I pressed the "correct!" button;
when I type number_wrong, I get the total number I pressed the "wrong!" button.

Comment: Where is your `play_correct` function, for example? Also, I don't think you can inspect variables during a Tkinter process... I could be wrong on that though

Comment: you define a callback and bind it to your button. see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a callback and bind it to your button

```
b1 = Button(app, text = "correct!", width = 10,
            command = play_correct)
b1.pack(side ='left', padx = 10, pady = 10)
b2 = Button(app, text = "wrong!", width = 10,
            command = play_wrong)
b2.pack(side ='right', padx = 10, pady = 10)

def play_correct():
    self.num_correct += 1

def play_wrong():
    self.num_wrong += 1
```

Additionally, you can bind the callback externally

```
b1 = Button(app, text = "correct!", width = 10,
            command = play_correct)
b1.pack(side ='left', padx = 10, pady = 10)
b2 = Button(app, text = "wrong!", width = 10,
            command = play_wrong)
b2.pack(side ='right', padx = 10, pady = 10)

def play_correct():
    self.num_correct += 1

def play_wrong():
    self.num_wrong += 1

b1.bind("<Button-1>", onCorrect)

b2.bind("<Button-1>", onNotCorrect)
```